# これらの研究の課題として4点挙げられる　ー＞ having problems understanding

Tags: academic-japanese, reading-comprehension

I'm reading a study with this sentence in it:

> これらの研究の課題として4点挙げられる。

I'm having problems understanding this. Are they saying there's a problem with the study?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Four points will be brought up as the subjects of this research/study.

You could use 課題 here to mean "problem" in the sense of an abstract problem -- i.e., the issues that the research is tackling.  It would not be "problem" in the sense of some difficulty in performing/conducting the research.